# Newcomer proposed a new project with greater scope than what my team is doing. Management is supporting the idea. How to protect my roadmap?

Tags: politics

My team has a product roadmap for a few specific projects.
A team of newcomers pushed a new project proposal in front of senior management. They love it.
This project takes some of the concepts in our product roadmap, and puts them in a much broader initiative.
I want to avoid losing control of my team's product roadmap. The scope is much bigger and complex than what we are working on, but the team behind the new proposal can't build anything without developers.
Now that senior management is enthusiastic about this new project, I am not sure what the right course of action is.
How to avoid a much bigger project take over my product roadmap?

Comment: Do your team have the time available to provide the added value? If not, make sure that is understood or provided by the newcomers...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes. Solar Mike: all our time goes to our roadmap. This new proposal has a much broader scope.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Now that senior management is enthusiastic about this new project, I
>   am not sure what the right course of action is.

Since you indicate that you are in control of your team's product roadmap, you meet with senior management and explain why you believe that your roadmap is better without inclusion of the new initiative.

And if senior management insists that the proposed initiative is their preferred path, you dig in, scope out a revised roadmap, and present it to senior management. This new roadmap might scrap the existing one, or be proposed as a follow-on to the current plans. Your presentation should cover all the costs and tradeoffs required to make the revised roadmap work.

Then, you solicit feedback and a decision from senior management, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Make sure that if other things have to be dropped to take on the new "scope" then management understand - they are good at **not** understanding if that is convenient...

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you are being too protective of *your* project and *your* roadmap.  It's the job of senior management to look at the bigger picture and decide what the company needs to do in the longer term.

The correct thing to do is to meet with management, so that you can understand what they want you to do, and make sure they understand what the implications will be for the project.  Will some parts of it need to be de-scoped in order to expand other parts, or will the team need to expand, or will the timescales need to be extended?

Answer (score 2):

Tell your management that the scope of the work has been made significantly larger, so you either need several additional developers, or the time frame to deliver will increase according to the additional workload.

The realisation that there is no such thing as a free lunch can often focus the mind.